# Terminal not executing Ruby files

Tags: ruby, command-line

I'm pretty much entirely new to programming, so bear with me. I am on a Macbook Pro running 10.6.6.

At the beginning of the ["Learn to Program"](http://pine.fm/LearnToProgram/?Chapter=01) tutorial are these directions:

> Save your program (yes, that's a program!) as calc.rb (the .rb is what we usually put at the end of programs written in Ruby). Now run your program by typing ruby calc.rb into your command line. It should have put a 3 on your screen. See, programming isn't so hard, now is it?

When I type `ruby calc.rb` I get the following error:

```
ruby: No such file or directory -- calc.rb (LoadError)
```

What am I doing wrong? "Calc.rb" is saved on my desktop, if it matters.

Comment: The problem you ran into isn't a programming one, it's because you don't have a basic understanding of using a computer at the command-line. I'd strongly urge learning about navigating using `PATH` and modifying it and when and WHY you would, and specifying a path to a file, either as an absolute path from the root of the drive, or a relative path from your home (`~/`) directory, or from the current (`./`) directory. That knowledge will make your programming experience much easier. StackOverflow is for programming questions. [SuperUser.com](http://superuser.com/) is for usability questions.

Answer (score 11):

If you have named your file "Calc.rb" you'll need to run `ruby Calc.rb` (capital "C").

Also make sure that you're navigating the `/Desktop` directory — e.g. type

```
cd ~/Desktop
ruby Calc.rb
```

You can use `ls` to get a list of all the files in the current directory. You could use that to see if the file you're trying to execute actually exists.

Answer (score 1):

In Terminal, did you change your current directory to your desktop before running your program ?

If your program is stored on your desktop, you first need to change directory to your desktop or your Ruby script will not be found.

```
$ cd Desktop
$ ruby calc.rb
```

Comment: Yup, I was actually on my school's wireless directory (?). But I changed it to desktop and the file executed.

Answer (score 1):

ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30) [i386-mingw32]

C:\Ruby Programs>ruby **calc.rb**

ruby: **No such file or directory -- calc.rb (LoadError)**

C:\Ruby Programs>ruby **calc.rb.txt**

**3**

One should not have to add the .txt extension while attempting to run the program from whithin the program's home folder.  I have to though.

Comment: If you're saving with Notepad, make sure you choose `All Files (*.*)` in `Save As Type` in its Save dialog.

Comment: That's not his problem, right? He has the well-named file on his desktop, he said. Also, text is more understandeable than prompts, for human who are not machines.

Answer (score 0):

Did you call your file Calc.rb and saved it as a rb file to. becouse then its called internaly. Calc.rb.rb
and be sure to run cmd from desktop :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you're running the command in the same directory you have the calc.rb file.

Type "cd " then the directory calc.rb is in to change it.

Then just do "ruby calc.rb"