# Why won't Terminal execute Ruby files?

Tags: ruby, terminal

I did a search, and found "[Terminal not executing Ruby files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737127/terminal-not-executing-ruby-files)" which seems relevant, but it doesn't answer the question I have.

I'm running OS 10.5.8, using Terminal and TextMate-1. I created a file containing `1+2` and saved it as "calc.rb" in my Desktop.

I did `cd Desktop`, but can't get Terminal to execute the command `calc.rb`. Typing `ls` shows the file. When I type  `ruby calc.rb` a new command line comes up as if I never typed a command.

As an alternative, I've been using repl.it and everything works there so I'm unsure if I have something set up wrong or if I'm just missing something.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. As a pointer for future questions, there is no need, nor is it desirable, to be so verbose. Try removing all unnecessary text. This isn't a forum, it isn't a bulletin-board, it's a Q&A site, somewhat like Wikipedia, so conciseness and accuracy are desired and appreciated. As is, you're likely to get "TL;DR" comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1+2` just evaluates `1+2`.  Unless you output the result, it simply get swallowed.

Change your `1+2` to `puts 1+2` and your script will output 3.

Comment: That was it. I actually completely blanked on the 'puts' and didn't even see it in the instructions. Didn't have my coffee this morning ugh. I'll pay more attention from now on. Ridiculous noob mistake. Thanks so much